# Designing database related methods, which is better to return: true/false or row affected?

Tags: design, error-handling, methods

I have some methods that perform some data changing in a database (insert, update, and delete). The [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) I'm using return row-affected int values for those type of method. What should I return for "my method", in order to indicate the success/failure state of the operation?

Consider the code that is returning an `int`:

A.1

```
public int myLowerLevelMethod(int id) {
    ...
    int affectedRows = myOrm.deleteById(id)
    ...

    return affectedRows;
}
```

Then usage:

A.2

```
public void myOtherMethod() {
    ...
    int affectedRows = myLowerLevelMethod(id)

    if(affectedRows > 0) {
        // Success
    } else {
        // Fail
    }
}
```

Compare to using boolean:

B.1

```
public boolean myLowerLevelMethod(int id) {
    ...
    int affectedRows = myOrm.deleteById(id)
    ...

    return affectedRows > 0;
}
```

Then usage:

B.2

```
public void myOtherMethod() {
    ...
    boolean isSuccess = myLowerLevelMethod(id)

    if(isSuccess) {
        // Success
    } else {
        // Fail
    }
}
```

Which one (A or B) is better? Or pros/cons of each?

Comment: In your "A.2". If zero rows are affected, why is that a failure if zero rows need to be affected? In other words if there is not a database error, why is it failure?

Comment: Is there a semantic difference between "unsuccessful" and "zero rows affected"? Eg, when deleting all orders of a customer, there is a difference between "customer does not exist" and "customer has no orders".

Comment: Do you consider a delete with zero rows unexpected? In that case throw.

Comment: @Arian I think that is the real question for me. I think I'd chose B, because with A, my code now contains checking for 0 in some places and for -1 in others

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Another option is to return a result object instead of basic types. For example:

```
OperationResult deleteResult = myOrm.deleteById(id);

if (deleteResult.isSuccess()) {
    // ....
}
```

With this, if for some reason you need to return the numbers of rows affected, you simply can add a method in OperationResult:

```
if (deleteResult.isSuccess()) {
    System.out.println("rows deleted: " + deleteResult.rowsAffected() );
}
```

This design allows your system to grow and include new functionality (knowing about affected rows) without modifying existing code.

Comment: +1 "This design allows your system to grow and include new functionality (knowing about affected rows) without modifying existing code" This is the right way of thinking about this category of questions.

Comment: I did similar thing in my old project. I have wrapper Request and Result object. Both use Compositions to include more details. and both have basic data in it as well. In this case, the Result object has a status code and a msg field.

Comment: Especially for a system using an ORM, I would call this best practice. The ORM in question may already include such result object type(s), too!

Comment: Just looking at the OPs example, all I can think of is that deleteById will return 2 at some point :) so definitely a custom type, yes.

Comment: I like this approach. I think it is non-blocking, cover both of my approaches, and modifiable/expandable (in future, if needed). The only downside I can think of is it's a bit more code, especially when it come in the middle of my project. I'll mark this as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @HoangTran, don't underestimate the cost of a "little more code". I downvoted this answer because that's actually one of the most costly things you can do. Even though in absolute terms the complexity here is not very much, compared to the possible alternatives this answer is actually significantly more complex. Image if you made everything this much more complex than you have to. Then you end up with a whole program significantly more complex than it has to be. This answer violates KISS and YAGNI and is not the right approach (see my answer for a more detailed explanation of this point).

Comment: That said, if your requirements change in the future end you do end up needing more information about the operation aside from success/failure, the method outlined in this answer is an excellent way to encapsulate the information.

Answer (score 12):

Returning the number of affected rows is better because it gives additional information about how the operation proceeded.

No programmer will blame you because he/she has to write this to check if they got some changes during the operation:

```
if(affectedRows > 0) {
    // success
} else {
    // fail
}
```

but they will blame you when they'll have to know the number of affected rows and they realize there are no method for getting that number.

BTW: if by "failure" you mean a syntactical query error (in which case the number of affected rows is obviously 0) then throwing the exception would be more appropriate.

Comment: -1 because of the reason you gave. Giving additional information is not always a good idea. Often, better design would led to communicating to the caller just what it needs, and nothing more.

Comment: @MainMa nothing stands in way of creating overloaded methods. Additionally, in native languages (C family for example), number of rows can be used directly in logic (0 is false, anything else is true).

Comment: @PTwr: so to cope with the fact that the method is returning too much information, you suggest creating an overload? This doesn't seem right. As for "zero is false, non-zero is true", this is not the point of my comment, and is a bad practice in some languages.

Comment: @MainMa I suggest overload to provide interface for all common situations. If "casting" result to bool occurs often, it will validate building it into function as redundant code is bothersome. In case of updating database amount of updated rows is rather important (eg. "N products updated") with result of 0 usually bound to incorrect WHERE conditions, ability to bind 0 to false allows for tricks that were considered good practice until programmers got spoiled with frameworks. 0-1 logic is what CPU uses, "boolean" is a lie.

Comment: Probably I am one of the spoiled programmers for I don't think that using any *tricks* could be considered good practice. In fact, whenever I have to deal with someone else's code I am thankful to whoever wrote it and did *not* employ any tricks.

Comment: You should always return the number of affected rows here!!! Since you can't possibly know if number of rows = 0 is a failure, or if number of rows = 3 is a success? If someone wants to insert 3 rows and only 2 get inserted you would return true, but it is not right! And if someone wants to `update t set category = 'default' where category IS NULL` even 0 affected rows would be a success, because now there is no item without category, even if no rows were affected!

Comment: @PTwr: The number of rows affected is a *number*; in cases where such cast will map any non-zero value to 1, such casting may be appropriate with the result of a bit-flag masking operation (which would, if such thing existed, use an operator which returned `true` if the operands had any bits in common), but less so when dealing with a count.  I would consider `rowsAffected > 0` a much more appropriate way of writing the success condition than `(bool)rowsAffected`.

Comment: I have tried this, then there's a question: should I check for 0 or -1 as the failure flag? This is somewhat depend one what I really want in specific situation, as someone commented. In fact, after a while, my code contains both checking for 0 or -1 in several places. That's why I think of using unified boolean version (and why I ask this question in the first place)

Comment: @Falco on the other hand, returning 0 doesn't always means an unsuccessful db change, for e.g: delete all items in a (empty) shopping cart. I think what the dev want to identify here is the key point.

Comment: Exactly! And because of that you have to think about each single case - what numbers constitute failures and what numbers are a success? - In most cases you will see the number doesn't matter at all - if there is no exception, it was a success! But in some cases you check for a specific number!

Answer (score 10):

I would not recommend any of them. Instead, return nothing (void) on success and throw an exception on failure.

This is for exactly the same reason I choose to declare certain memebers of class private. It also makes function easier to use. More operational context does not always mean better, but it certainly means more complex. The less you promise, the more you abstract away, the easier it is for the client to understand and the more freedom you have in choosing how to implement it.

The question is how to indicate success/error. In this case it's enough to signal failure by throwing an exception and return nothing on success. Why do I have to provide more than the user needs?

Failures/exceptional situations can happen and then you'll have to deal with them. Whether you use try/catch to do it or examine the return codes, is a matter of style/personal preference. The ideas behind try/catch are: separate normal flow from exceptional flow and let exceptions bubble up to the layer where they can be handled most appropiately. So, as many have pointed out already, it depends on whether failure is really exceptional or not.

Comment: -1 Why would you return nothing where you could return something, with no negative side effects, that provides extra operational context?

Comment: For exactly the same reason I choose to declare certain memebers of class private. It also makes function easier to use. More operational context does not always mean better, but it certainly means more complex. The less you promise, the more you abstract away, the easier it is for the client to understand and the more freedom you have in choosing how to implement it.

Comment: Sure, you might have more implementation freedom, but the user needs to be able to get data from your code. Otherwise, it's useless.

Comment: Well, what data does the user actually needs to get? The question is how to indicate success/error. In this case it's enough to signal failure by throwing an exception and return nothing on success. Why do I have to provide more than the user needs?

Comment: @proskor: Exceptions are for exceptional cases. "Failure" in this scenario may be an expected outcome. By all means, put this forward as a potential alternative, but there isn't enough information here to make a recommendation.

Comment: The user needs to know a little bit about the result in this particular case. The method should return what it can back to the caller.

Comment: Exceptions are good in cases where a function does not behave as expected.  In some cases, however, a caller may want to "do something if possible", fully *expecting* that it might not be possible.  Having a means by which the caller can request an exception in case of failure is good, but it shouldn't be the only option.

Comment: If I understand correctly, following @proskor way involves creating a custom Exception type and then throw/catch it. I personally don't like using custom exception for logic/flow control. I've marked AlfredoCasado's as the answer. His approach also need to create a custom type, which I think cleaner than throwing/catching.

Comment: 'I personally don't like using custom exception for logic/flow control.' - that's ok. But failures/exceptional situations can happen and then you'll have to deal with them. Whether you use try/catch to do it or examine the return codes, is a matter of style/personal preference. The ideas behind try/catch are: separate normal flow from exceptional flow and let exceptions bubble up to the layer where they can be handled most appropiately. So, as many have pointed out already, it depends on whether failure is really *exceptional* or not.

Comment: -1 Exceptions should not be part of normal program flow. It is unclear what "failure" means in the context of your error, but an exception in the context of a database call should be due to an exception that occurs in the database. Affecting zero rows should _not_ be an exception. A mangled query that cannot be parsed, references a nonexistent table, etc. would be an exception because the database engine would choke on it and throw.

Answer (score 2):

"Is this better than that?" is not a useful question when the two alternatives don't do the same thing.

If you need to know the affected row count, then you *must* use version A. If you don't have to, then you can use version B - but any advantage you might gain in terms of less code-writing effort is already gone since you took the trouble to post both versions to an online forum!

My point is: which solution is better depends entirely on what your requirements specifically for this application are, and you know those circumstances much better than we do. There is no industry-wide, safe-to-use, best-practice, won't-get-fired-over-it choice that is better *in general*; you have to think about it yourself. And for a decision as easily revised as this one, you needn't spend all that much time thinking either.

Comment: I agree that this depends much on the app requirements. However it seems that this kind of situation is not very unique, and I'm not looking for a silver bullet but just other's experience dealing with the same/similar thing (maybe the question is a bit misleading, I do like suggestions other than A/B)

Answer (score 1):

Two of the most important principles in maintainable software design are *KISS* and *YAGNI*.

- [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle): Keep it Simple, Stupid
- [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI): You Aren't Gonna Need It

It is almost never a good idea to put in logic you don't immediately need *right now*. Among many other people, Jeff Atwood (a co-founder of StackExchange) [wrote about this](http://blog.codinghorror.com/kiss-and-yagni/), and in my experience he and other proponents of these concepts are completely right.

Any complexity you add to a program comes at a cost, paid over a long period of time. The program becomes more difficult to read, more complex to change, and easier for bugs to creep in. Don't fall for the trap of adding things "just in case". It's a false sense of security.

You are rarely ever going to get any code right the first time. Changes are inevitable; adding in speculative logic to defensively prepare for unknown future contingencies *will not actually protect you* from having to refactor your code when the future turns out to be different than you expected. Upkeep on unnecessary/contingent logic is more of a maintainability problem than refactoring later to add in missing functionality.

Thus, since it appears that all your program needs for now is to know whether the operation succeeded or failed, your proposed solution B (return a single boolean) is the correct approach. You can always refactor it later if the requirement changes. This solution is the simplest and has lowest complexity (KISS) and does just what you need and nothing more (YAGNI).

Answer (score -1):

### The whole rows or an error status

Consider returning the whole rows, at least as a run-time option. In DB inserts you may need to inspect the data that was inserted - since it often will be different from what you sent to the DB; common examples include autogenerated row IDs (that the app will likely immediately need), default values determined by DB, and results of triggers if you use them.

On the other hand, if you don't need the returned data, then you also don't need the affected row count, since it's not helpful for the result of 0. If there are mistakes, then you need to return *what kind* of mistake happened, in a way consistent to your project error handling principles (exceptions, numeric error codes, whatever); but there are valid queries that will correctly affect 0 rows (i.e. "delete all expired orders" if there actually aren't any).